# Allowing user to perform regression analysis based on select variables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app to allow the user to upload a CSV, select a dependent and independent variable(s) and then perform a regression analysis. So far I have been able to upload the file, and select the columns of interest based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248364/shiny-not-reacting-to-uploaded-csv-to-allow-user-to-select-columns/67252666?noredirect=1#comment118883437_67252666) answer. But the app is not being able to construct the `lm` `model`. The purpose is to first generate and display `lm` results by using the `summary` and then produce some plots. How can I allow the user to perform a simple regression analysis? The sample file can be downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/08be32mxvwcrhpk0xusxbyz3oh2ho4ix).

UI

```
ui = navbarPage(tabPanel("Regression Analysis,
                         dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                         sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", "Please choose a CSV file",
                                                              multiple = T,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                                                    radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                                                 choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                                                             Semicolon = ";",
                                                                             Tab = "\t"),
                                                                 selected = ","),
                                                    radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                                                 choices = c(None = "",
                                                                             "Double Quote" = '"',
                                                                             "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                                                 selected = '"'),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                                                                 choices = c(Head = "head",
                                                                             All = "all"),
                                                                 selected = "head")
                                                    
                         ),
                         mainPanel(
                           tableOutput("contents")),),
                         actionButton("choice", "Define Regression Variables"),
                         selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                selectInput("independent1", "Independent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                selectInput("independent2", "Independent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                tableOutput("Table_selected.col"),
                textOutput("regTab")
))
```

Server

```
# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  mydf <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    df = read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                  header = input$header,
                  sep = input$sep,
                  quote = input$quote)
    
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }
    
  })
  
  output$contents = renderTable({
    req(mydf())
    mydf()
  })
  
  # Code for allowing the user to select the variables/columns of interest 
  info <- eventReactive(input$choice, {
    req(mydf())
    f <- mydf()
    f
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$choice, {  ## to update only when you click on the actionButton
  #observe({
    req(mydf())
    updateSelectInput(session,"dependent", "Please Select a Dependent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            updateSelectInput(session,"independent1", "Please Select a Independent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            updateSelectInput(session,"independent2", "Please Select a Independent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            
  })
  
  
  output$Table_selected.col <- renderTable({
    input$choice
    req(info(),input$columns)
    f = info()
    f = subset(f, select = input$columns) #subsetting takes place here
    head(f)
  })

output$independent1 = renderUI({
            req(mydf())
            checkboxGroupInput("independent1", "Independent Variable:",names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent],names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent])
        })
        
        output$independent2 = renderUI({
            req(mydf())
            checkboxGroupInput("independent2", "Independent Variable:",names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent],names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent])
        })
        
        runRegression = reactive({
            req(mydf())
            Model.2 = lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent1,collapse="+"),"+",paste(input$independent2,collapse="+"))),data=mydf())
            Model.2
            })
        
        output$regTab = renderPrint({
            if(!is.null(input$independent)){
                summary(runRegression())
            } else {
                print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
            } 
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE**

After following the answer below, I am now getting new errors.

```
ui = navbarPage(tabPanel("Regression Analysis,
                         dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                         sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", "Please choose a CSV file",
                                                              multiple = T,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                                                    radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                                                 choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                                                             Semicolon = ";",
                                                                             Tab = "\t"),
                                                                 selected = ","),
                                                    radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                                                 choices = c(None = "",
                                                                             "Double Quote" = '"',
                                                                             "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                                                 selected = '"'),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                                                                 choices = c(Head = "head",
                                                                             All = "all"),
                                                                 selected = "head")

                         ),
                         mainPanel(
                           tableOutput("contents")),),
                         actionButton("choice", "Define Regression Variables"),
                         selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                selectInput("independent1", "Independent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                selectInput("independent2", "Independent Variable:", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
                uiOutput("dependent"),
                uiOutput("independent1"),
                uiOutput("independent2"),
                textOutput("regTab")
))
```

Server

```
# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        mydf = reactive({
            
            # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
            # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
            # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
            
            req(input$file1)
            
            df = read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                           header = input$header,
                           sep = input$sep,
                           quote = input$quote)
            
            if(input$disp == "head") {
                return(head(df))
            }
            else {
                return(df)
            }
            
        })
        
        output$contents = renderTable({
            req(mydf())
            mydf()
        })
        
        # Code for allowing the user to select the variables/columns of interest 
        info = eventReactive(input$choice, {
           req(mydf())
           f = mydf()
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$choice, { ## to update only when you click on the actionButton 
            req(mydf())
            updateSelectInput(session,"dependent", "Please Select a Dependent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            updateSelectInput(session,"independent1", "Please Select an Independent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            updateSelectInput(session,"independent2", "Please Select an Independent Variable:", choices = names(mydf()))
            
            })
        output$Table_selected.col = renderTable({
            input$choice
            req(info(), input$columns)
            f = info()
            f = subset(f, select = input$columns) #subsetting takes place here
            head(f)
        })
        
        output$dependent = renderUI({
            req(mydf(), input$independent1)
            radioButtons("dependent", "Dependent Variable:",choices=names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% as.character(input$independent)])
        })
        
        output$independent1 = renderUI({
            req(mydf(),input$independent1)
            radioButtons("independent1", "Independent Variable:",names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent],names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent])
        })
        
        output$independent2 = renderUI({
            req(mydf(),input$independent1,input$independent2, input$dependent)
            radioButtons("independent2", "Independent Variable:",names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent],names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$dependent])
        })
        
        runRegression = reactive({
            req(mydf(), input$independent1, input$independent2, input$dependent)
            Model.2 = lm(reformulate(input$dependent,input$independent1, input$independent2),data=mydf())
            })
        
        output$regTab = renderPrint({
            req(runRegression())
            if(!is.null(input$independent)){
                summary(runRegression())
            } else {
                print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
            }
```

Errors

The last two actiobButtons for output$independent1 and output#independent2 are returning:

```
Warning: Error in radioButtons: The 'selected' argument must be of length 1
```

The `lm(reformulate)` line and `renderPrint` are

```
Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(nnet)

ui = navbarPage(tabPanel("Regression Analysis",
                         dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                         sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(width=3, fileInput("file1", "Please choose a CSV file",
                                                              multiple = T,
                                                              accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                         ".csv")),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                                                    radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                                                 choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                                                             Semicolon = ";",
                                                                             Tab = "\t"),
                                                                 selected = ","),
                                                    radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                                                 choices = c(None = "",
                                                                             "Double Quote" = '"',
                                                                             "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                                                 selected = '"'),
                                                    tags$hr(),
                                                    radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                                                                 choices = c(Head = "head",
                                                                             All = "all"),
                                                                 selected = "head")

                           ),

                           mainPanel(
                             tableOutput("contents"),
                             actionButton("choice", "Define Regression Variables"),
                             selectInput("independent", "Independent Variables:", choices = NULL, multiple = T),
                             uiOutput("dependent1"),
                             #tableOutput("Table_selected.col"),
                             verbatimTextOutput("regTab")
                           )
                         ),

))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  mydf <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    df = read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                  header = input$header,
                  sep = input$sep,
                  quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

  output$contents = renderTable({
    req(mydf())
    mydf()
  })

  # Code for allowing the user to select the variables/columns of interest
  info <- eventReactive(input$choice, {
    req(mydf())
    f <- mydf()
    f
  })

  observeEvent(input$choice, {  ## to update only when you click on the actionButton
    req(info())
    updateSelectInput(session,"independent", "Please Select independent Variable(s):", choices = names(info()) )
  })


  # output$Table_selected.col <- renderTable({
  #   input$choice
  #   req(info(),input$columns)
  #   f = info()
  #   f = subset(f, select = input$columns) #subsetting takes place here
  #   head(f)
  # })

  output$dependent1 = renderUI({
    req(mydf(),input$independent)
    radioButtons("dependent1", "Select a dependent Variable:",choices=names(mydf())[!names(mydf()) %in% input$independent])
  })

  ###  need to build your formuila correctly; It will work with multiple independent variables
  ###  model <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$IndVar, input$DepVar), data = RegData)})

  runRegression <- reactive({
    req(mydf(),input$independent,input$dependent1)
    lm(reformulate(input$independent, input$dependent1), data=mydf())
    # multinom(reformulate(input$independent, input$dependent1), data=mydf())  ### mulitnomial from nnet package
  })

  output$regTab = renderPrint({
    req(runRegression())
    if(!is.null(input$independent)){
      summary(runRegression())
    } else {
      print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Why are there two dependent (dependent 1 and dependent2) variables in the code? Actually, the lm formula that I am using is something like this lm(dependent ~ independent1 + independent2). I am sorry if my question wasn't clear on this.

Comment: I am getting new errors now, so I am updating the question to include those errors too.

Comment: I have also uploaded a sample file to make the code reproducible.

Comment: Please try the updated code.  It has been adjusted to select multiple independent variables.

Comment: Thank you, the code works fine now but the results are not correct, you see when you do lm(formula = SWE ~ Mean.Z + Intensity.mean, data = Mean_SWE) I get this https://app.box.com/s/1ci67nx1hfjb1ynhv0jrid9rae0tww0u. And as you can see the results are quite different, so maybe the lm formula in the shiny app code needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, you can change the formula or use mulitnom from nnet package or some other package.  Also, please ensure that you are looking at the whole dataset not just head (first 6 records).

Comment: Thank you, this worked, so now I have posted a new question where now I am going to the next step in the app where now based on the lm model, interactive regression plots will be created using autoplot and autoplotly using the ggfortify package. Since you are familiar with the code and sample data, can you please look at it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274572/using-autoplotly-in-shiny-app-with-user-selected-columns